# Elasticsearch completion - generating input list with analyzers

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I've had a look at this article: https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me
However, it requires writing some logic in the client to create multiple "input". Is there a way to define an analyzer (maybe using shingle or ngram/edge-ngram) that will generate the multiple terms for input?

Here's what I tried (and it obviously doesn't work):

```
DELETE /products/
PUT /products/
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": {
                    "type":"shingle",
                    "max_shingle_size":5,
                    "min_shingle_size":2
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {"type": "string"
                ,"copy_to": ["name_suggest"]
                }
                ,"name_suggest": {
                    "type": "completion",
                    "payloads": false,
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT /products/product/1
{
    "name": "Apple iPhone 5"
}

PUT /products/product/2
{
    "name": "iPhone 4 16GB"
}

PUT /products/product/3
{
    "name": "iPhone 3 GS 16GB black"
}

PUT /products/product/4
{
    "name": "Apple iPhone 4 S 16 GB white"
}

PUT /products/product/5
{
    "name": "Apple iPhone case"
}

POST /products/_suggest
{
    "suggestions": {
        "text":"i"
        ,"completion":{
            "field": "name_suggest"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you managed to build your suggest field this way?

Comment: Can you please specify what is desired output when you just type 'i' with your sample data? and it would be really helpful if you can provide expected inputs.

Comment: @xrage I'm not the OP but what I would expect is to get all of the documents (1 through 5), as suggestions.

Comment: after hitting my head against this for a while, I ran some trial-and-error experiments and determined that a `completion` field *will* work without an `input` field, and it will even use a custom analyzer... however, it seems to skip the tokenizer part of the analyzer, which makes is very hard to use for anything other than keywords

Answer (score 4):

Don't think there's a direct way to achieve this. 
I'm not sure why it would be needed to store ngrammed tokens considering elasticsearch already stores the 'input' text as an FST structure. New releases also allow for fuzziness in the suggest query.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#fuzzy

I can understand the need for something like a shingle analyser to generate the inputs for you, but there doesn't seem to be a way yet. Having said that, the `_analyze` endpoint can be used to generate tokens from the analyzer of your choice and those tokens can be passed to the 'input' field (with or without any other added logic). This way you won't have to replicate your analyzer logic in your application code. That's the only way i can think of to achieve the desired input field.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So the closest possible thing (right now at least) is to do a request to `_analyze` and then using the results for that in the `input` field. Good to know!